# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel'

Tags: jquery

Hit there, I have a conflict in my new joomla 3.1 site and one of the modules I use is not working properly because of that error (I guess):

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel'

Do you have any idea wthat is Jcarousel and how I can not have it anymore;

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

jCarousel is a jQuery plugin for controlling a list of items in horizontal or vertical order.
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Your error is most likely being caused by you trying to use the plugin before including the jQuery library (or maybe you are including it more than once).